# Static css file not loading in Django admin

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-admin

I'm trying to load my own css file to replace base.css in order to customize Django Admin

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}VSPM{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Django administration') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/theme.min.css" %}{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

But the css file isn't loading in Django admin. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% block extrastyle %}{% static "admin/css/theme.min.css" %}{% endblock %}
```

Change your block name and try

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your project.
2. Copy this folder `/virualent_path//lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin` to 'static' folder of your project.
3. Add this string to the settings.py:  `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')`
4. Then run this command: `python3.6 manage.py collectstatic`